# mongodb cluster with ELB endpoint as dns

Tags: mongodb, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

This is not a technical but more of architectural question I am asking here.

I have followed this [blog](https://medium.com/@greeshu.renu/how-to-setup-three-member-replica-set-on-amazon-ec2-mongodb-60f0aaddcf32) for setting up the mongodb cluster. We have 2 private subnets in which I have configured 3 member replica set of mongodb. Now I want use a single dns like `mongod.some_subdomain.example.com` for whole cluster.
I do not have access to Route53 and setting/updating the dns records takes at least 2 hours in my case since I am dependant on our cloud support for it. I am not sure which server primarily responds to applications requests in mongodb cluster.
So is there a way to put the whole cluster behind ELB and use ELB as DNS to route traffic to primary and at the same time if there is failover then next primary would be the member of ELB except the arbiter node.

Answer (score 0):

The driver will attempt to connect to all nodes in the replica set configuration. If you put nodes behind proxies the driver will bypass the proxies and try to talk to the nodes directly.

You can proxy standalone and sharded cluster deployments as the driver doesn't need a direct connection to data nodes in those but mapping multiple mongoses to a single address can create problems with retryable reads/writes, sessions, transactions etc. This is not a supported configuration.

Comment: Ok. So do I have to put all 3 servers under ELB or Putting primary and secondary would suffice for application traffic being routed to the correct node?