# MongoDB Community Kubernetes Operator Connection

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to deploy a MongoDB replica set by using the MongoDB Community Kubernetes Operator in Minikube. To view the content of the database I would like to connect to the MongoDB replica set through Mongo Compass.
I followed the instructions on the official GitHub, so:

- Install the CRD
- Install the necessary roles and role-bindings
- Install the Operator
- Deploy the Replicaset

The yaml file used for the replica set deployment is the following one:

```
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: mongo-rs 
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  members: 3 
  type: ReplicaSet 
  version: "4.4.0" 
  persistent: true 
  security:
    authentication: 
      modes: ["SCRAM"]
  users:
    - name: user
      db: admin
      passwordSecretRef: 
        name: user
      roles:
        - name: userAdminAnyDatabase
          db: admin
      scramCredentialsSecretName: user-scram
  additionalMongodConfig:
    storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.journalCompressor: zlib    
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: user
type: Opaque
stringData:
  password: password
```

The MongoDB resource deployed and the mongo-rs pods are all running. Also, I'm able to connect to the replica set directly through the mongo shell within the Kubernetes cluster.
Anyway, I'd like to connect to the MongoDB replicaset also from outside the Kubernetes cluster, so in addition I've created a LoadBalancer service like the following one:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mongo-rs-svc
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      nodePort: 30017
```

The pods (namely *mongo-rs-0*, *mongo-rs-1*, *mongo-rs-2*) are correctly binded to the service. On cloud providers that support load balancers, an external IP address would be provisioned to access the Service. On minikube, the LoadBalancer type makes the Service accessible through the *minikube service* command, which generates a tunnel for the service *mongodb-service* (for instance: 127.0.0.1:34873), but if I try to connect to the MongoDB replica set through the Mongo Compass client using the connection string:

> mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:34873/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=mongo-rs&readPreference=primary

The client cannon't connect to mongodb, returning the error:

> getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> mongo-rs-0.mongo-rs-svc.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local

Any suggestions on how to access the replica set from outside kubernetes?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I know it's possible to connect from the outside using port forwarding, but I'd be interested in a more production-oriented approach.

Comment: You cannot front replica set nodes with proxies. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733502/mongodb-cluster-with-elb-endpoint-as-dns/67739255#67739255.

Comment: Hi Federico, I' having troubles installing the community operator, as I see you have through the installation flawlessly would you mind having a look at miry question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154993/mongodb-community-operators-custom-resource-definitions-afre-not-recognised-in ?
My problem is that when I start editing a yaml file as soon I add the `kind` parameter both `apiVersion` and `kind` parameter get underlined and the the error message is that the kind is not part of the schema.. so I guess I haven't installed it properly..
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

minikube is a development app. So for you it may be sufficent to connect from your host(desktop) via localhost.

So first you can't use the type LoadBalancer, because this round robins between the mongodb instances, but only the primary in the replica set can write.
Normaly the mongo client with the right connection string will select the primary.
So take nodePort and you will get a connection to one mongodb instance.

Make a kubectl port-forward <resource-type/resource-name> [local_port]:<pod_port>` to the service

Before that you may change the mongodb-service. As far as I know it's not nodePort, its targetPort

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mongo-rs-svc
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

So something like that

```bash
kubectl port-forward mongodb-service 27017:27017
```

Aftert that you may connect you mongodb from `localhost:27017` to the kubernetes service, which connects you to the mongo replica.

```bash
mongo localhost:27017
```

should connect. Edit the ports on your needs

Hope this idea helps,