# Reverse proxying MongoDb for Replica Set and/or Shard mode?

Tags: mongodb, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, envoyproxy, replicaset

How to reverse proxy MongoDb nodes with Replica set using any of the reverse proxies (say nginx/Envoy)? As per my understanding, a replica set has one primary and multiple secondary hosts and hence cannot be used simply for load balancing while proxying. So how would one go about reverse proxying a Mongo Db database as an upstream? Can the same be achieved for Shard mode as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733502/mongodb-cluster-with-elb-endpoint-as-dns/67739255#67739255

Comment: Thanks @D.SM for the response. Does this behavior apply to all the mongo clients? Like when I use a C# mongo driver I can see that it bypasses the proxy after the initial connection but for other clients like Robo 3T and mongo shell, the connections break if I stop the proxy after the initial connection is made. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes, but the drivers differ in whether topology discovery is the default behavior. If it isn't you get a direct connection.